# what is the table of products in magento 2?

Tags: products, magento2.3.5-p2

I want to know what is the table in the magento 2 database, which stores the product information as the description. I found a table called "quote_item" but there are a lot less products than I have in the store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product data is stored across a number of tables. The main one is `catalog_product_entity`. Anything not in that table will be stored in `catalog_product_entity_int`, `catalog_product_entity_text`, `catalog_product_entity_decimal`, `catalog_product_entity_varchar`, `catalog_product_entity_datetime`. Additionally you need to use the `eav_attribute` table which will tell you which values in the other tables are for which attributes.